# Confused about injective functions (concept): $g(x) = (5x^2 + 15)^{7777}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am confused about the concept of one-to-one functions when applying it to problems. I know that a one-to-one function has one $x$ for every $y.$ I was given the function:

$g(x) = (5x^2 + 15)^{7777}$

and I had to explain why $g$ is not a one-to-one function. I couldn't really explain the answer but the only thing that came to my mind was because it has a power of $7777.$ The possible answers are 
a) It is not a one to one function because some y values have two x values.
b) It is not a one to one function because some y values have three x values.
c) It is not a one to one function because some x values have no y value.
d) It is not a one to one function because some x values have two 2 values.
e) It is not a one to one function because some y values have one x value.
The answer I chose was **d**, but it was incorrect. The correct answer was **a**.

I am really confused as to how to apply the concepts to solve this problem. Could someone shed some light on this topic? I would really appreciate it! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $g(x)$ is a (real) function then a given $x$ defines a unique $y$ by $g(x)$,
what you answerd said that there is an $x$ s.t that $g(x)$ can take two values - but that is clearly not the case.

The meaning of $1-1$ is that if $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$ then $x_1=x_2$ - that is it can't be that more then one $x$ is mapped to the same $y$.

Answe $a)$ say that the definition does not hold since there is a $y$ value with $x_1,x_2$ s.t $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$ **but** $x_1\neq x_2$ . Can you find such example to prove that the function is not $1-1$ ?

Comment: I see my mistake since I misread the answer d. However I am still confused as to how an individual would find how many answers that function has.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "how many answers that function has" ?

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a way to figure out how many x or y values the function had. For example x^2 has two answers. I am a little confused as to how many answers x^7777 has. Is it also two? Is there ever a case where there are three possible answers to a function?

Comment: There is no general thing to say here - given a function $g(x)$ and a $y$ value you need to check how many $x$ values are mapped to that $y$, this number can be any number. for example define $g$ by $g(0)=g(1)=g(2):=1$ and for every other number define $g$ to be $0$

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint}$ : $g$ is an even function.

Move cursor over the box for more details.

> Note that for all $x$, $g(x) = g(-x)$. This is because $g(x) = (5x^2 + 15)^{7777} = (5(-x)^2 + 15)^{7777} = g(-x)$. Hence, you have, for example, $g(1) = g(-1)$. So $f$ is not injective because both $1$ and $-1$ map to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that a one to one function has one x for every y.

It is **at most** one x for every y. Then you can see why the above is not one to one.